# Codename one form appearance changed

Tags: android-layout, themes, codenameone

Is there any change in CN1 default theme?
Here is my form what it was looking prior on the phone

(it has list item background and square button by default)
[image]

Then all of a sudden from last 2 days, without changing anything in themes.res from my side, list item background and button shape have disappeared & button caption became all caps. As per this
[image]

This happened across the whole app and all of my 4 apps. Please may I know is the change going to be revert from the CN1 side or this is an enhancement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's explained in this blog post:
https://www.codenameone.com/blog/pixel-perfect-material-buttons.html